# SAT - Hardness of determining backbone literals

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, sat

Let $F$ be a CNF formula. Let $l$ be one of $F$'s literals.

> **Question**
>   Which is the complexity of determining whether $l$ is a backbone literal or not? The obvious way to do that is to propagate $\lnot l$ on $F$, obtaining $F'$: $l$ is then a backbone literal of $F$ if and only if $F'$ is unsatisfiable. I'm asking if there is another way.

Comment: Isn't that just SAT of $F\land\lnot l$? That is, it's NP-complete. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Radu GRIGore: What you say is of course right, it is the obvious and natural way to do that: just reduce the question to SAT (note this doesn't mean the question is NP-complete too). I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: *Backbone* literals look very similar to *frozen* variables. There are ways to determine/approximate them in random k-CNF literature.

Comment: For practical algorithms, I believe [Marques-Silva, Janota, and Lynce](http://sat.inesc-id.pt/~mikolas/ecai10.pdf) is a good place to look.

Comment: @Radu: Thanks for the pointer to that paper. I'm reading it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complexity is *co-NP* complete because you're converting to **un**satisfiability of $F \land \lnot l$. I have a proof of the completeness in my [PhD thesis, Claim 2](http://sat.inesc-id.pt/~mikolas/th.pdf) (if I may blatantly advertise myself).

There's a small problem for unsatisfiable formulas, if your definition of a backbone means that all the literals are backbone for an unsatisfiable formula, then the problem stays in *co-NP*. If, however, the set of backbone literals is empty for an unsatisfiable formula, you also need *NP*.

Comment: I prefer the definition where all the literals are backbone for an unsatisfiable formula.